# Cassandra nodetool repair hangs

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.0

A Cassandra 2.0.6 cluster consists of two DCs with a few nodes. There are ongoing writes, but nothing that the cluster would not handle. Under this small pressure I run *nodetool repair -par -pr* which should run repair in parallel, only for the primary range for the given node. The repair is run once at a time. Sometimes an error occurs:

> Streaming error occurred java.io.IOException: Connection timed out

but as streaming_socket_timeout_in_ms is set to 10 minutes, the streaming should be retried on its own I presume. Looking through the logs, it looks like the repair is finally finished as next entries are only about compactions.

How can I know that a node is hanging should be restarted?
What's going on with the nodetool?